# Access 2002 form - display customer details

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to display various customer (contact) details in a text box on a form.  These include address details. I recently (today) asked a similar question to this, and got a great answer - use DLookUp.  `=DLookUp("[address_line_1]","[address]", _
"[contact_id]= '" & [Forms]![contacts1]![contact_id] & "'")`

This works well for one field (in the above case `address_line_1`).  I'd like to now show the city, country, and post/zip code, concatenated, and on one line. I have tried a variation of the above code, but the documentation for DLookUp is clear that it only works on one field, so did not work for me: `=DLookUp("[city]+[country]+[postcode]","[address]", _
"[contact_id]= & [Forms]![contacts1]![contact_id])` (the `contact_id' is auto generated int).

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a number of SQL-like statements for the data to be returned. The concatenation operator in MS Access is &, not +. Concatenating with + can return null, for example, Null + Value = Null.

```
DLookUp("[city] & [country] & [postcode]","[address]", _ 
   "[contact_id]=" & [Forms]![contacts1]![contact_id])
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment, and as far as I have asked it you provided a correct answer. I fear, however, I have not asked the correct question.  I will try again in a different question, providing more detail. Thank you for your input, and I apologise for the imprecision I used in asking my question.